# Htaccess - Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com, BUT for different top level domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, tld

A website of mine is accessible through different URL:

```
studienbuch.ch
studienbuch.at
studienbuch.com
```

I'd like to have them changed to www.studienbuch.tld, but keep the top level domain:

```
studienbuch.ch -> www.studienbuch.ch
studienbuch.at -> www.studienbuch.at
studienbuch.com -> www.studienbuch.com
```

How to handle that with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work (untested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.studienbuch\.(ch|at|com)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.studienbuch.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's unfortunately not yet doing the trick. 

It forwards the page to "www.studienbuch." without adding the top level domain.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [R=301,L]
```